# In Laravel 8, how to redirect to home in case on 500 error

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm using Laravel 8, in production my `.env` set to `APP_DEBUG=false` but I don't want show a 500 view, I need redirect to mysite.com/home if Laravel returns a 500 error.

In Laravel docs (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/errors) explain how to handle errors but i can't understand it, im new in Laravel 8.

My app/Exceptions/Handler.php is:

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
use Throwable;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    /**
     * A list of the exception types that are not reported.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontReport = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * A list of the inputs that are never flashed for validation exceptions.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontFlash = [
        'password',
        'password_confirmation',
    ];

    /**
     * Register the exception handling callbacks for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->reportable(function (Throwable $e) {
            //
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For 5xx error code, you can catch the error code using

Two approach

**First Approach**

Using Symfony Package

```
use Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Exception\FlattenException;

...

public function render($request, Exception $exception) {
    //
    if (FlattenException::create($exception)->getStatusCode() == 500) {
        // (For 5xx codes)
        return redirect()->route('home');
    }
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

**Second Approach**

Using **\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ServerException**

**Inside app/Exceptions/handler.php**

```
if ($exception instanceof \GuzzleHttp\Exception\ServerException) {
    // (For 5xx codes)
    return redirect()->route('home');
}
```

Comment: I get: PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of App\\Exceptions\\Handler::render($request, Exception $exception) must be compatible with Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler::render($request, Throwable $e)

Comment: Added a new way. Please try using first approach

Answer (score 0):

you can handel `Exception` and get status code by `getStatusCode()`

```php
use Exception;

/**
 * Register the exception handling callbacks for the application.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    $this->reportable(function (Exception $e) {
        logger($e); 

        if($e->getStatusCode() == 500 ){
            return redirect('/');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: the question is "in case of 500 error". ModelNotFoundException is 404

Comment: @Ricardinho that is only the example 500 error cased various reason so if you want to catch all then   ignore that `if ($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException)` and just redirect on that function or you can listen for any event

Comment: 404 and 500 are completely different errors. Your answer is uncompleted.

Comment: @Ricardinho check now

Comment: Thanks, i get error: production.ERROR: Call to undefined method ErrorException::getStatusCode() {"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0): Call to undefined method ErrorException::getStatusCode()